# Galaxy S6 settings widget

Tags: settings, tethering, app-widgets, samsung-galaxy-s-6, quick-settings

I want to add a shortcut to the tethering/mobile hotspot setting, but I can't find the settings widget. Does this not exists? Is there a way to add it to the quick settings (swipe down from top)?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I could come up with was to install [Power Toggles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.painless.pc), and add a shortcut to my homescreen. From unlocked, this is 1 tap. And if locked, because I use fingerprint unlock, it's hardly more than 1 tap anyway.

I can't use root because this is a work-supplied phone, and some required software won't work if the phone is rooted.

Answer (score -1):

**Note: Root access is required**.

Follow the instructions:

1. Install [SQLite Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.sqleditor).
2. Open the app and look for "Setting Storage" entry
3. Select "Setting Storage" and then select `settings.db`
4. Next select "system". This would be the last item on the list
5. Tap on the search icon and search for "notification" and select "OK"
6. Tap on the Plus sign "+" to add new parameter
7. Under `name`, type the following: "notification_panel_default_active_app_list"
8. In the Value field, type all the toggle you want in there. I usually do a copy and past from a text file to avoid any mistake
9. Hit the same button
10. Select "notification_panel_active_app_list" and paste/type the same value as in step 8. above and save it.
11. You could do the same for "notification_panel_default_active_app_list_for_res t"

Additionally, you could increase the number of scrollable toggles from 10 to any value you want. I usually have it at 20. The parameter you need is the "notification_panel_active_number_of_apps"

You can also add SFinder and QuickConnect to the toggle list and you can then get rid of those two in the drop down to have more space in the notification area.

I have provided a list of the toggle I commonly use as a text. Please note that some toggles might not be relevant to the ROM you're using and might not work or do anything when toggled. E.g. Don't expect touch to work if it hasn't been implemented in your ROM version, and so on.

You can never loose any toggle again and you can add more as needed.

```
Wifi; MobileData; Location; Bluetooth; AutoRotate; Torc hLight; MultiWindow; SilentMode; Ebook; NetworkBooster ; SideKey; WiFiHotspot; AllShareCast; SBeam; Sync; Toddl erMode; SmartStay; SmartPause; SmartScroll; SmartNetwo rk; Nfc; PowerSaving; UltraPowerSaving; AirplaneMode; A irView; AirGesture; Toolbox; CarMode; QuickConnect; SFi nder;NetworkBooster;TouchSensitivity; DoNotDisturb; DormantMode; Brightness; PersonalMode;
```

Comment: The point is I want to be able to access this without having to go into the settings app in the first place. On all my previous Android phones, I had a widget for tethering, so it was 2 taps to turn it on. Now, it's several.

Comment: the solution I have proposed allow you to select a new quick settings widget, so you can swipe and toggle

Comment: you have to go into settings app only once

Comment: Ok, on my device I don't have that option in the quick settings widget.

Comment: I'll post some photos mate

Comment: This is what I see: http://1drv.ms/1GuiDRI

Comment: that edit , see my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24948/discussion-between-crunch-and-andrea-cinesi).

Comment: check my new answer mate, hope it helps

Comment: Does this need root? I can't root this phone.

Comment: root access is required,  sadly